# Problem displaying panels and menu in kubuntu 13.10

Tags: graphics, kubuntu, 13.10

After updating kubuntu to 13.10 the panels and menu stopped displaying normally. What it looks like now is: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B9w7i5IjbxAhZzJUNzdWQjhqNFU&usp=sharing
The problem is that the same happens also in Kubuntu LiveCD.
How can I solve that?

I'm running Toshiba Satellite A200-14D with 3GB RAM, default nvidia graphic card and Win7HP on the other partition.

Comment: Is the system full updated ? Do you have open source driver(nouveu) or a closed one(nvidia) ? and if you have Nvidia's driver installed, which one ? (number)

Comment: System is full updated. How can I check drivers version?

Comment: `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 vga` , if returns `Kernel driver in use:nvidia` , then issue `dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've experienced this on a Dell laptop with a Quadro FX 350M video card on a fresh install of Kubuntu 13.10.  To get a usable Graphical interface, I used the shift+alt+F12 key combo to turn off desktop effects (they're on by default).

Then I went to the K menu->System->Additional Drivers program and activated one of the proprietary driver options for my video card (uses nouveau by default on fresh install).  Once it was finished the item showed a yellow icon so I rebooted and things seem to be displaying properly once I've turned desktop effects back on.

Since you did an upgrade you may already have a proprietary driver in place, you may need to remove, reboot, then re-install it.  NikTh seems knowledgeable in figuring this out if that's the case.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Actually worked :)